# I want to display map without using any JS library directly by fetching API from website

Tags: javascript, rest, api, dictionary

I want to fetch map from mapmyindia API. But it is showing Showing error 
"Access to fetch at "url" from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled."

Below is my program. what wrong I am doing.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial- 
scale=1.0">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
<title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
<button id="mybtn">fetch it</button>
<script>
    document.getElementById("mybtn").onclick=()=>{
        fetch("http://apis.mapmyindia.com/advancedmaps/v1/<Key>/still_image?center=28.595939499830784,77.22556114196777&zoom=18&size=800x480&ssf=1&markers=28.595939,77.225561|28.596000,77.225600>")
        .then(data=>{
            return data.json()
        }).then(data2 =>{
            console.log(data2)
        })

    }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I usually bypass this by writing my own server which acts as a proxy between your frontend and the target.  That way you dont get CORS errors.  I have had to do this as well when it comes to requesting non-SSL requests from a secure web application, i needed to create wrappers in order to secure them.  I would write a small exposed API on the machine which hosts your websever and this should resolve itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to send a no-CORS-safelisted request-header name. Send a header from the list below:

- `Accept`
- `Accept-Language`
- `Content-Language`
- `Content-Type`

Reference: https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#no-cors-safelisted-request-header-name